# Change src attribute execute_script selenium python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am trying to apply this line

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('#StudentImage').setAttribute('src', 'Photos/' + stdCode + '.jpg');")
```

The line works only if I entered the value of stdCode variable directly, but when using the variable `stdCode`, I got this error

```
JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: stdCode is not defined
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.114)
```

When trying these lines like that

```
sPath = 'Photos/' + stdCode + '.jpg'
with open(sPath, 'rb') as f:
    my_string = base64.b64encode(f.read())
    sBase64 = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + ''.join(map(chr, my_string))
    print(sBase64)
#driver.execute_script(f"document.querySelector('#StudentImage').setAttribute('src', 'Photos/' + {stdCode} + '.jpg');")
driver.execute_script(f"document.querySelector('#StudentImage').setAttribute('src', {sBase64});")
```

I got this error

```
JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: missing ) after argument list
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.114)
```

Comment: stdCode is a Python variable?

Comment: Yes it is in the python code and it is defined.

Comment: It looks fine from Python perspective. 
Maybe some Javascript issue? Check here for some info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_parenthesis_after_argument_list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that stdCode is a Python variable, you can use the common way for using variables inside a string:

```
driver.execute_script(f"document.querySelector('#StudentImage').setAttribute('src', 'Photos/' + {stdCode} + '.jpg');")
```

Comment: Can you please have a look at the updated question?

Comment: Hmmm strange. What if you add one more closing parenthesis at the end of the query like below?
{sBase64}))

Comment: This doesn't work too. I tried to add apostrophes before and after the variable but this doesn't work too.